# How to verify PayPal webhook in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, paypal, webhooks

I have tried to set up verification as shown [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature_post) and I keep getting the error: `{ error: 'invalid_token', error_description: 'Token signature verification failed' }`.

Here is what my verification function looks like:

```
export const verifyPayPalWebhook = async (req: NextApiRequest) => {
  const url =
    "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature";
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      transmission_id: req.headers["paypal-transmission-id"],
      transmission_time: req.headers["paypal-transmission-time"],
      cert_url: req.headers["paypal-cert-url"],
      auth_algo: req.headers["paypal-auth-algo"],
      transmission_sig: req.headers["paypal-transmission-sig"],
      webhook_id: process.env.PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID,
      webhook_event: req.body,
    }),
  });

  const data = await res.json();

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(data.error_description);
  }
  return data.verification_status === "SUCCESS";
};
```

I have confirmed that both `PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET` and `PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID` environment variables are defined. The `PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET` is the 'secret' for my application and `PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID` is the webhook ID for the specific webhook.

I am testing my webhook endpoint by creating and capturing an order on my development server that will eventually notify the webhook endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make REST API calls, you first need to use the secret and corresponding client_id to obtain a valid oauth2 token (which can be cached for 9 hours if desired)

The easiest way to do it in node is to reuse the sample function from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

```
// For a fully working example, please see:
// https://github.com/paypal-examples/docs-examples/tree/main/standard-integration

const { CLIENT_ID, APP_SECRET } = process.env;
const baseURL = {
    sandbox: "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com",
    production: "https://api-m.paypal.com"
};

// generate an access token using client id and app secret
async function generateAccessToken() {
  const auth = Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID + ":" + APP_SECRET).toString("base64")
  const response = await fetch(`${baseURL.sandbox}/v1/oauth2/token`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${auth}`,
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.access_token;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I finally got the webhook to verify! You mentioned that you can cache the token for 9 hours. Would storing the token in my database along with the time it was created be a good approach to caching the token?

Comment: Less persistent storage would be more appropriate, but a database would work. It's optional in any case.

Comment: https://github.com/paypal-examples/paypal-sdk-server-side-integration is a robust typescript example that includes caching